# Minifying a Flask application when templates have inline JS?

Tags: python, flask, minify, bundling-and-minification

The normal convention before deploying an application is to minify all assets (css, html, js). This usually assumes that all the assets are in an independent file (ie, all js code is in `/js/mycode.js`, which makes minifying the assets easier.

However, I have written a bunch of jinja2 templates that have `<script>` tags in them, and they make use of the template's variables. This has been useful for quickly writing UI quickly, but I'm wondering what the best way of migrating all this into one js file so that I can do minification later?

For example, I have lots of templates that have inline js:

```
<div class="some_content">
    <button>{{mytext}}</button>
</div>
<script>
    $(".some_content button").click(function() {
        $(this).text("{{new_text}}");
        $.post("{{url_for('doit', name=name)}}", function() {
            console.log('Done!');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am aware that I can stuff the js code into a file and then do `{% include 'mycode.js' %}`, but then I'd be importing ALL of my js code into the template. Some templates have inheritance, so then doing the include statement will cause the file to load the entire scripts multiple times into the page (not good). And I'm not sure how including scripts like this would work with minification.

Is there a good way to move all the inline JS code to an external file, without losing the benefits of jinja2's template variables, so that I can minify my javascript? Or rather, what's a good way to minify all my inline JS?

Answer (score 5):

You can use jinja-assets-compressor for this.

https://github.com/jaysonsantos/jinja-assets-compressor

**app.py**

```
from jac.contrib.flask import JAC
from flask import Flask, render_template
import jinja2
from jac import CompressorExtension

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['COMPRESSOR_DEBUG'] = app.config.get('DEBUG')
app.config['COMPRESSOR_OUTPUT_DIR'] = './static'
app.config['COMPRESSOR_STATIC_PREFIX'] = '/static'
jac = JAC(app)

env = jinja2.Environment(extensions=[CompressorExtension])
env.compressor_output_dir = './static'
env.compressor_static_prefix = '/static'
env.compressor_source_dirs = './static_files'


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', name='rublex')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Flask test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <button onclick="sayHi()">Say Hi</button>

        {% compress 'js' %}
        <script>
            function sayHi() {
              alert('{{ name }}');
            }
        </script>
        {% endcompress %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Outputs JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/62280e86f267fdbbd0cd10bb7b5ae3dc.js"></script>

function sayHi(){alert('rublex');}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want simple inline js-minification, no output files... Here's what I did:

Took some time to get a simple custom jinja2 tag/node to work, but hopefully this helps anyone who might need something like this. This is likely not done the best way, but it works well enough. This runs the same "js-compressor" that [jinja-assets-compressor](https://github.com/jaysonsantos/jinja-assets-compressor) does:

> [rjsmin](https://pypi.org/project/rjsmin/)  -  rJSmin is a javascript minifier written in python, based on the semantics of jsmin.c by Douglas Crockford.

#### Include this code snippet somewhere in you jinja2 code:

**JSMinifyExtension**

```py
from jinja2 import nodes as j2_Nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension as j2_Extension

import rjsmin  # https://pypi.org/project/rjsmin/

class JSMinifyExtension(j2_Extension):
    # simple js-minify for jinja2 
    # by joedf (2021) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66018269/883015

    # a set of names that trigger the extension.
    tags = {"jsminify"}

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(JSMinifyExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        self._body_content = ""

    def parse(self, parser):
        tag = parser.stream.current.value
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno

        body = parser.parse_statements(['name:end{}'.format(tag)], drop_needle=True)
        self._body_content = body[0].nodes[0].data

        return j2_Nodes.CallBlock(self.call_method('_jsminify'), [], [], []).set_lineno(lineno)

    def _jsminify(self, caller):
        minified = rjsmin.jsmin(self._body_content, keep_bang_comments=False)
        return minified
```

#### And you can load in this extension into your jinja2 environment like so:

```py
My_Example_Jinja_Env = Environment( extensions=['jinja2.ext.do', JSMinifyExtension] )
```

#### and use it your templates like so:

```js
{% jsminify %}
function mySpecialFunction() {
    return 42;
}
{% endjsminify %}
```